# Virtual Machine Isolation

Tags: virtual-machines, resource-management

I am not a sysadmin, but I'm curious about what goes on behind the scenes.

We have a virtual machine at work which my group logs into to do secure data processing.  The OS is Windows Server 2008 R2; I don't know what hypervisor is used.  Occasionally, all the system resources will be used up and it will run as slow as molasses.  This happens despite no one in my group accessing or running a process.  My suspicion is that the VM is one of several on the host machine and that another instance is doing something to hog the host system's resources.

I suspect there are competing considerations for running multiple virtual machines on the same host.  What are trade-offs have to be made?  What tools and strategies exist for balancing these considerations?

Comment: What is the hypervisor and what OS are you running within the virtualized space?

Answer (score 1):

> What tools and strategies exist for balancing these considerations

Find a sysadmin, talk to him. It is very likely there is overallocation, but your possibility to find that out really depends on breaking the hypervisor wall - someone needs to look at the hardware layer.